# Can a Unicode document be properly indexed with LaTeX?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, xindy

I'm trying to create a proper index for a book that uses Unicode throughout. By *proper*, I mean an index with (i) entries, subentries and sub-subentries, as appropriate; (ii) indexing of spans of text; (iii) index entries with clickable links for the page numbers; and (iv) certain formatting within index entries.

My document is in Spanish, and uses Unicode, as I said above. Changing this is impossible. I must also continue to use the `polyglossia`, `hyperref`, `glossary` and `cleverref` packages, as they are integral to the entire book. Therefore, removing any of these packages is a non-solution.

I use `TexStudio` with `Xelatex` from TexLive 2020. For indexing, I am using `imakeidx` with `xindy`. It is my understanding that `xindy` is one of only two Latex indexers, and that it is the only one that can handle Unicode. I am also using the `seealso` package, as it attempts to fix various problems that occur without it.

Here is an MWE. The errors are explained in the example.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% You may have to compile with --shell-escape

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,letterpaper,twoside,openright,spanish]{book}

% LANGUAGE CONFIG
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\SetLanguageKeys{spanish}{indentfirst=false}
\setotherlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}

% INDEXING
%\usepackage{showidx}  % Must be loaded before 'imakeidx'.
\usepackage[quiet,xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-C utf8 -M lang/spanish/modern-utf8-lang.xdy]
\usepackage{seealso}  % Must be loaded after imakeidx

% HYPERLINKS
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,bookmarksdepth=3,psdextra,spanish,plainpages=false,colorlinks=false,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},breaklinks=true,bookmarksopen=false,unicode=true,pdflang=es-ES]{hyperref}

% LOADED IN CASE THEY AFFECT XINDY
\usepackage[xindy={language=spanish-modern,codepage=utf8},translate=true,nopostdot,nonumberlist,seeautonumberlist]{glossaries} % Must be loaded after 'hyperref'
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}  % Must be loaded after 'hyperref'


% ---------- DOCUMENT BEGINS ----------
\begin{document}

This simple example is indexed properly\index{properly}, as people\index{people} expect.

We can also do sub-entries\index{structures!sub-entry} and sub-subentries\index{structures!sub-subentry} just fine.

Sub-entries can also be formatted\index{beautification!formatting@\textit{formatting}} fine.

Index headers can be formatted, with things like italics\index{italics@\textsl{italics}} and boldface\index{boldface@\textbf{boldface}}.

But...

ERROR: Jenny\index{Jenny|textbf} can't be bolded. In the index, no boldface is applied and no page number appears.

ERROR: Joe\index{Joe|textit} can't be italicized, either. An index entrey without italics or even a page number is generated.

ERROR: Poor Peter\index{Peter|see{people}} cannot be indexed as a person with \textit{see}. An empty space between two commas appears in his index entry.

ERROR: Unsurprisingly, Paul\index{Paul|see {people}}, with a space in his \textit{see} command, can't be indexed as a person either. An empty space between two commas appears in his index entry, too.

ERROR: Jen\index{Jen|seealso{people}} also breaks things when we want to \textit{seealso} her. Yet again, and empty space with commas on either side appears in her index entry.

ERROR: Jen\index{Jen|seealso {people}} still breaks things when we try to \textit{seealso} her with a space in the command.

ERROR: And the fail\index{fail|(} is total when we try to index a span of text.\index{fail|)}. This causes an empty index entry (except for a comma), and a compiler error, too.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

As the MWE shows, most indexing functions are broken -- formatting in index entries, the use of `see`, the use of `seealso`, indexing of spans of text.

How can these errors be fixed?

Comment: xindy's development seems to have stopped. I would either try xindex (https://ctan.org/pkg/xindex?lang=de) or bib2gls (https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls), the second requires a switch to another input method.

Comment: Actually, you can use the old good `makeindex` with Unicode, too, with the help of `esindex`. Only tested with `babel`, but it should work with `polyglossia`. See https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/esindex/esindex.pdf .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `xindex` looks very promising. As my MWE indicates, I use `xindy` for the glossary, too, and have done a great deal of customization for it (and it works perfectly for *that*). Do you know if it would be possible to continue to use `xindy` for the glossary and move over to `xindex` for indexing? The manual doesn't mention glossaries at all.

Comment: @JavierBezos Is there an MWE for your solution anywhere? The manual covers lots of details, of course, but I don't see this.

Comment: @GillWilliams I’ve tested it as is and it works for me with `makeindex`, without changing anything. Your example is in English, so I can't prepare a MWE from it for Spanish.